# operation inside map function in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to take the data from file name(as it contains some info.) and write those in csvfile_info file without using loop .
I am new in pyspark. Please some one help me in code and let me know how can i proceed.
This is what i tried...

Code: 
    c = os.path.join("-------")

```
input_file = sc.textFile(fileDir)
file1= input_file.split('_')
csvfile_info= open(c,'a')
details= file1.map(lambda p:
    name=p[0], 
    id=p[1],
    from_date=p[2],
    to_date=p[3],
    TimestampWithExtension=p[4]\
    file_timestamp=TimestampWithExtension.split('.')[0]\
    info = '{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5} \n'.\
    format(name,id,from_date,to_date,file_timestamp,input_file)\
    csvfile_info.write(info)
    )
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting. It would also help if you could provide a sample input file and the desired output.

Comment: A map function manipulates data. It's not a replacement for a loop. This doesn't work primarily because `csvfile_info` is not defined

Comment: Is there any another way to do without a loop. As loop is not the feasible solution in Spark. @cricket_007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to write the data inside of the `map()` function. You should instead map each record to the appropriate string, and then dump the resultant rdd to a file. Try this:

```
input_file = sc.textFile(fileDir)  # returns an RDD

def map_record_to_string(x):
    p = x.split('_')
    name=p[0]
    id=p[1]
    from_date=p[2]
    to_date=p[3]
    TimestampWithExtension=p[4]

    file_timestamp=TimestampWithExtension.split('.')[0]
    info = '{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5} \n'.format(
        name,
        id,
        from_date,
        to_date,
        file_timestamp,
        input_file
    )
    return info

details = input_file.map(map_record_to_string)  # returns a different RDD
details.saveAsTextFile("path/to/output")
```

Note: I haven't tested this code, but this is one approach you could take.

---

**Explanation**

From the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile), `input_file = sc.textFile(fileDir)` will return an [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD) of strings with the file contents.

All of the operations you want to do are on the contents of the RDD, the elements of the file. Calling `split()` on the RDD doesn't make sense, because `split()` is a string function. What you want to do instead is call `split()` and the other operations on each record (line in the file) of the RDD. This is *exactly* what `map()` does.

An RDD is like an iterable, but you don't operate on it with a traditional loop. It's an abstraction that allows for parallelization. From the user's perspective the `map(f)` function applies the function `f` to each element in the RDD, as it would be done in a loop. Functionally calling `input_file.map(f)` is equivalent to the following:

```
# let rdd_as_list be a list of strings containing the contents of the file
map_output = []
for record in rdd_as_list:
    map_output.append(f(record))
```

Or equivalently:

```
# let rdd_as_list be a list of strings containing the contents of the file
map_output = map(f, rdd_as_list)
```

Calling `map()` on an RDD returns a new RDD, whose contents are the results of applying the function. In this case, `details` is a new RDD and it contains the rows of `input_file` after they have been processed by `map_record_to_string`.

You could have also written the `map()` step as `details = input_file.map(lambda x: map_record_to_string(x))` if that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: what should be p in map_record_to_string(p) ?

Comment: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'split'
Getting this error. How can i spilit the file name.

Comment: @Learner, I updated the code and added some explanation. I hope this helps, but I suggest you read up on spark and rdds.

Comment: Thank you so much @pault :)

Comment: apologize @pault... Due to some network issue it didn't reflected

Comment: is it not recommended to write anything inside map function or its not allowed. I was having a similar use case and I tried to write data to HDFS inside map function but not able to do so. Not sure about the reason though, can you please help me understand this? @pault

Comment: @ManishMehra I'm not sure if it's allowed but it *may* be possible- I'm not sure and I don't know of any way. In any case, why can't you just map your records to an rdd of strings and write it out at the end?

Comment: for every id in the rdd, I am trying to make a REST API call. I can pass the resultant set corresponding to map id but i wanted to save the result in HDFS. so that once entire map operation is completed I can read all the files from the predefined HDFS location.