# Frequency of Words in a file using Python

Tags: python, pyspark, word-count

I'm trying to count the number of words by using a python program .

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="Words")
lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1], 1)
counts=dict()
words = lines.split(" ")
for word in words:
    if word in counts:
        counts[word] += 1
    else:
        counts[word] = 1

output = counts.collect()
for (word, count) in output:
    print "%s: %i" % (word, count)

sc.stop()
```

This was not giving me the desired output . Can there be any improvement to this code ?

Comment: Please include the desired and the actual output in your question.

Comment: Your question isn't about python- it seems to be a pyspark question. You should be getting a syntax error when you do `words = lines.split(" ")`.

Comment: A `dict` does not have a `collect` method.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are mixing up python and spark.

When you read the file using [`pyspark.SparkContext.textFile()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=textfile#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile) you will get an RDD of strings. Quoting myself from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48304272/5858851) to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304008/operation-inside-map-function-in-pyspark/48304272):

> All of the operations you want to do are on the contents of the RDD,
>   the elements of the file. Calling `split()` on the RDD doesn't make
>   sense, because `split()` is a string function. What you want to do
>   instead is call `split()` and the other operations on each record (line
>   in the file) of the RDD. This is exactly what `map()` does.

Here is how you can modify your code to count the word frequencies using pySpark.

First we will map each word `w` in each line into a tuple of the form `(w, 1)`. Then we will call `reduceByKey()` and add the counts for each word.

For example, if the line was `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`, the map step would turn this line into:

```python
[('The', 1), ('quick', 1), ('brown', 1), ('fox', 1), ('jumps', 1), ('over', 1),
 ('the', 1), ('lazy', 1), ('dog', 1)]
```

Since this returns a list of tuples, we will call [`flatMap()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=textfile#pyspark.RDD.flatMap) so that each tuple is considered as a unique record. One other thing to think about here is whether or not you want the counts to be case sensitive and if there is any punctuation or special characters to remove.

After the `flatMap()`, we can call [`reduceByKey()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=textfile#pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey) which gathers all tuples with the same key (in this case the word) and applies the reduce function on the value (in this case `operator.add()`).

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext
from operator import add

sc = SparkContext(appName="Words")
lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1], 1)  # this is an RDD

# counts is an rdd is of the form (word, count)
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: [(w.lower(), 1) for w in x.split()]).reduceByKey(add)

# collect brings it to a list in local memory
output = counts.collect()
for (word, count) in output:
    print "%s: %i" % (word, count)

sc.stop()  # stop the spark context
```